# Why is React's useEffect hook not called here before the function returns?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, promise, axios, use-effect

The `useEffect` hook below should set the `weather` variable, but it is not doing so -- instead, the React component returns before the hook is called.

**Why is the `useEffect` hook not called before the React component returns, and how can I fix this problem?**

```
// A React component that shows a given city's weather.
const CityWeather = ({ city }) => {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({})
 
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json` +
        `?key=${process.env.REACT_APP_MY_SUPER_SECRET_WEATHER_API_KEY}` +
        `&q=${city}`)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(`response is ${JSON.stringify(response)}`)
        setWeather(response.data)})
  },
  [city])

  console.log(`The value of the weather var is ${JSON.stringify(weather)}`)
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Weather in {city}</h2>
      <p>temperature: {weather.current.temp_c} Celsius</p>
      <img src={weather.current.condition.icon} alt="weather forecast"/>
      <p>wind speed: {weather.current.wind_mph} mph</p>
      <p>wind dir.: {weather.current.wind_dir}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: you might be getting an error, weather seems to be an array (based on its initial value) and you are accessing it as an object

Comment: Take a look at this [lifecycle diagram](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) and note the the "return/render" is invoked and processed during the "render" phase and effects are invoked in the "commit" phase where `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` are called. This is simply how the react component lifecycle functions. Effects are ***always*** called *after* the component has rendered. Your `weather` state is also defined as an array but you access as if it were an object in the return.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks, effects always coming after renders would explain it. (Btw `weather` is indeed supposed to be an object, I just initialized it as an array as a mistake. Edited my OP so that `weather` is initialized as an empty object instead of empty array (I would leave it for others to see and learn from if not for the fact that it distracts from the real heart of the problem, which you've also addressed))

Comment: @DrewReese Also, could you please suggest an alternative for getting API data which doesn't suffer from this problem? Getting API data seems common enough that there ought to be a standard way to do it in React

Comment: The "standard" way is to make "asynchronous" calls to fetch data when the component mounts, be that in `componentDidMount` in class-based components, or in the first triggering of the `useEffect` hook in functional components. You have to handle the conditional rendering while data is not populated yet.

Comment: Thanks -- to confirm, the "`useEffect` + conditional rendering" way of doing this would be like what neeko does in his answer below? (showing a placeholder until the data is retrieved)

Comment: That would be a correct confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the call to the api is asynchronous, which means that the code will continue to execute whilst the fetch happens in the background, when a response is returned it will then callback in the `.then()` part of the effect.

A common practice is to show a placeholder whilst loading data:

```
const CityWeather = ({ city }) => {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json` +
          `?key=${process.env.REACT_APP_MY_SUPER_SECRET_WEATHER_API_KEY}` +
          `&q=${city}`,
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(`response is ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
        setWeather(response.data);
      });
  }, [city]);

  console.log(`The value of the weather var is ${JSON.stringify(weather)}`);
  return (
    <div>
      {!weather ? (
        <h3>Loading the weather!</h3>
      ) : (
        <>
          <h2>Weather in {city}</h2>
          <p>temperature: {weather.current.temp_c} Celsius</p>
          <img src={weather.current.condition.icon} alt="weather forecast" />
          <p>wind speed: {weather.current.wind_mph} mph</p>
          <p>wind dir.: {weather.current.wind_dir}</p>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

(Also, I noticed you defaulted `weather` to an array (`[]`) which is probably causing other issues)

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Just to check my understanding, would things always happen in the following sequence? (1) The page renders and shows the placeholder. (2) `useEffect` gets data from the API and calls `setWeather`. (3) Since `weather` has changed due to `setWeather`, the page re-renders, thus displaying the weather details

Comment: Yeah it depends on the time it takes for the api to respond with the `weather`. 

1. First render - no `weather`, api request to get the weather is dispatched
2. Waiting for response
3. Response received, state updated, `weather` displayed on second render